# Strange behavior to replace string with '$_' using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am copying a delimited substring from a string to another. The delimiters are #! and !#. The first string have my "Immutable Content" and I want to put it inside another string.

For example:

Original String:

```
"Lorem Ipsum #! My Immutable Content !# Lorem Ipsum"
```

Template String:

```
"This is a test #!-!# It worked."
```

Produces:

```
"This is a test #! My Immutable Content !# It worked."
```

This works fine. But if my original string has the string '$_' the result string is unexpected:

Original String:

```
"Lorem Ipsum #! My Immutable $_ Content !# Lorem Ipsum"
```

Produces:

```
"This is a test #! My Immutable This is a test #!-!# It worked. Content !# It worked."
```

It seems the original string is all inside the new string.

The code that produces this result is listed below

```
string content = "Lorem Ipsum #! My Immutable $_ Content !# Lorem Ipsum";
string template = "This is a test #!-!# It worked.";

Regex regexOld = new Regex(@"(?<all>#!(?<text>[\w\d\s.""\r\n':;\{\}\[\]\(\)\+\-\*!@#$%^&<>,\?~`_|\\\/=]*)!#)");
MatchCollection mcOld = regexOld.Matches(content);

foreach (Match match in mcOld)
{
    Regex regexNew = new Regex(@"(?<all>#!(?<text>[\w\d\s.""\r\n':;\{\}\[\]\(\)\+\-\*!@#$%^&<>,\?~`_|\\\/=]*)!#)");
    template = regexNew.Replace(template, match.Groups["all"].Value);
}
```

I would like to know two things:

1. Why the string "$_" causes this behavior?
2. How to workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_` has a special meaning in a replacement string, it represents the input string. To solve your problem, you probably need to escape it like this: `$$_`

Comment: Yes, that's fixed my problem. But, where I found some documentation about this?

Comment: Is it a general solution to replace all $ by $$? Or do we need to replace only the defined `$number`, `${name}`, `$&` etc.? Is there a method provided by .NET which does Regex escaping? It seems that there's at least no `RegexOption` which would avoid such special meanings.

Comment: @ThomasW.: Yes, in other words, when you want a literal `$` in the replacement pattern you must escape it with an other `$`.